# Engine Knocking after running low on oil - Hyundai Coupe

Tags: engine, oil, noise, hyundai, hyundai-coupe

Is this the end of my engine?

I was driving on the motorway and started to hear a repeated knocking noise from the engine. 10 minutes later the oil light came on, I stopped and checked the oil. It was dry. I added oil to the engine and the noise seemed to get worse as I accelerated?

There is now a knocking noise when the engine runs at idle and it gets worse when I accelerate. Going to mechanic tomorrow, but hoping you guys might have some suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Knocking noises from an engine aren't good especially if they are related to oil starvation. It is not possible to exactly determine what is wrong just from your description, but is very well possible to be an expensive noise (rod bearing for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knocking, in whatever form, is not good for the engine. I'd suggest your issue is most likely a rod knock, which may be caused by a spun bearing. The reason I suggest this is, when you added oil, it didn't do your engine any good as far as the noise goes. If you continue to run on a spun bearing, the bearing will seize and cause more severe damage to the engine, such as throwing a rod out the side of the block. Yes, would suggest your engine is most likely toast at this point.